# Multiple data query and only showing it once

Tags: php, database, arrays, mysqli

Hi i have a php script which takes the data from the database my problem is that the data from column 1 - 50 is the same i want to make it display the data that has the same name only once

The database is like this

```
     --------------------------------------------
     Country | State | Name | Address|
     --------------------------------------------
     Japan   | Ohio  | Bill
     Japan   | Ohio  | Anne
     Japan   | Ohio  | Shyru
     Japan   | Nagoia| Ayusawa
     Japan   | Nagoia| Neji
     Japan   | Nagoia| Kaito
     Japan   | Osaka | Suwabara
     Japan   | Osaka | Kai
     Japan   | Osaka | Jane
```

And I want to get the data Ohio , Nagoia and Osaka or any state that that would be added here but would only print the ohio only once

this is my code below:

```
     <?php
     $con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","test");
     if (mysqli_connect_errno())
       {echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();}
     $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ftable ORDER BY Country");
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
       {
         echo $row['State'];
       }
     mysqli_close($con);
     ?>
```

and this code shows this

```
    Ohio Ohio Ohio Nagoia Nagoia Nagoia Osaka Osaka Osaka
```

and i only what it to show the state only once how can i do that? and thanks for ready this! any help would be really help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a group by clause

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ftable GROUP BY State ORDER BY Country");
```